# Cannot resolve bean driverClassName

Tags: java, spring

When I create a Spring-config xml ,I got an error when I add dataSource, It says cannot resolve bean.

[image]

My `spring.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dqbz" />

    <!-- 配置整合mybatis过程 -->
    <!-- 1.配置数据库相关参数properties的属性：${url} -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <!-- 2.数据库连接池 -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <!-- 基本属性driverClassName、 url、user、password -->
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried removing the following comment from within the bean definition?

```
<!-- 基本属性driverClassName、 url、user、password -->
```

Comment: This should be a comment hence it does not answer the question.

Comment: I'm glad you're so quick to jump to conclusions @YassinHajaj.  In looking at the configuration I can see no other issues - and based on the title of the post it's complaining about a bean named "driverClassName."  There are also chinese characters in the comment.  Who knows how that's being parsed.

Comment: XML doesn't really care where you stick comments so long as the rest of the document is semantically correct.

Comment: Also for edification, I can also replicate the OP's issue, even if I typed the properties out.

Comment: Can't replicate this.  I copied into STS exactly as per the post and I do not see any problems.

Comment: @neal Don't take it too personal. This should just be a comment. It'd have had the same exact impact on the question.